# Show that $y=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

I'm thinking of approaching this with the ratio test,

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{x}{n+1}$. I know that the limit of this ratio as n approaches infinity is zero, therefore the series must converge?

Comment: Yes. If the limit is $0$ then the radius of convergence is infinite so it converges for all $x$.

Comment: Yes, it converges for any $x\in\Bbb R$ provided that the ratio test is passed for any $x$ (indeed it converges for any $z\in\Bbb C$ too.)

Comment: What is there to converge? Do you mean the corresponding sequence (infinite series)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. The series
$$1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$$
is the well-known Taylor series of expansion of $e^x$ about $x = 0$.